# Export ggplot to editable powerpoint

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my own data and want to make a bar plot for x(Year) and y(average of duration in days). Then I want to export this plot to editable pptx slide. I learnt quite a few examples here and there and try to adjust to my task.

But R produces the error

> "Error in ph_with.dml(`*tmp*`, value = p_dml, ph_location()) :
> inherits(value$ggobj, "ggplot") is not TRUE". fyi I'm using R markdown in my macbook.

Please help me to fix the errors.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(mschart)
library(here)
library(glue)
library(viridis)
library(purrr)

Project_stages <- read_excel(
    "/Users/giang/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-GCF/Documents/R/Test w 
     R/Project stages 131122.xlsx")

Project_stages_1 <- Project_stages%>%
  filter(Stage %in% c("00. PI received",
       "01. Stage 3: CN received",
       "04. Stage 4: FP received",
       "14. Stage 6: Approved")) %>%
  spread(key = Stage, value = 'Day of Stage Date') %>% 
    select(`Approved Ref`,Index,PI =`00. PI received`,
             CN=`01. Stage 3: CN received`,
              FP=`04. Stage 4: FP received`,
                Approved='14. Stage 6: Approved') %>% 
     mutate(Project_received= as.Date((ifelse(!is.na(PI), as.character(PI), 
                                                ifelse(!is.na(CN), 
      as.character(CN), ifelse(!is.na(FP), as.character(FP), "")))),
                                      format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
    filter(Index==1) %>% 
    mutate(duration= as.numeric(difftime(Approved,Project_received, 
       units = "days")), Sub_Year= as.numeric(format(Project_received, 
       format= "%Y")))

p <- Project_stages_1 %>% 
  select(duration, Sub_Year) %>% 
  group_by(Sub_Year) %>% 
  summarise(Avrg= round(mean(duration)),
            Mdn= round(median(duration)))

ggplot(p, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="#a13458") +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Duration of project submission to GCF")

p

p_dml <-dml(ggobj = p) %>%
read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide("Title and Content", "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(p_dml, ph_location()) %>%
  print(target = here("results2.pptx"))
```

Comment: Your `p` object is the aggregated dataset you use for the plot, not the plot itself, i.e. it is a dataframe or tibble.

Comment: ^ so you could add `p_plot <- ` before your `ggplot(p ....` code so that the output is saved to that object, and then use `p_dml <- dml(ggobj = p_plot)`.  Alternatively, you could use `p_dml <- dml(ggobj = last_plot())` to retroactively use your last plot.

Comment: Thank you Stefan and Jon for guiding me through. I have managed to do it. I will try Jon's suggestion in a minute.